# Suggestions for dynamically creating static angularjs templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, optimization

I want to optimize some of my angularjs codebase, and I want to do this by generating optimized, targeted, static templates.  Ideally, I would generate these templates dynamically so that I only need to maintain a single template, and that template will generate .. other templates.  A quick (very simplified) example to clear up any confusion...

the following could be used to generate 2 static templates

templateGenerator.html

```
<div>
    <!-- if args.view == true -->
      <span ng-bind="data"></span>
    <!-- else -->
      <input ng-model="data"></span>
    <!-- endif -->
</div>
```

template1.html

```
<div>
  <span ng-bind="data"></span>
</div>
```

template2.html

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="data"></span>
</div>
```

**What are some good options for doing this?**

One thing I'm considering is using `underscore.js` as the templating engine in `templateGenerator.html` and rendering during build time via a grunt task.

The major thing I'm concerned about with that approach is.. Mixing templating engines. I can't use angular as the template processor in `templateGenerator.html` (at least I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work).  Would using underscore as the templating engine for `templateGenerator.html` make the code too convoluted?.

Comment: What is the problem with using `ng-include`

Comment: @Chandermani I don't see how that is applicable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options are listed below

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-template

I ended up using processhtml and am quite happy with it